# Cannot resolve parameter 'Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository' in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abp

I am trying to create some tenants for my test. I am using the template created at the ABP Framework website (.NET Core, Angular, version 4.4). In my TestBaseModule, I have added this:

```
private static void SeedTestData(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
{
    AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () =>
    {
        using (var scope = context.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            await scope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<IDataSeeder>()
                .SeedAsync();

            scope.ServiceProvider                            // This
                .GetRequiredService<TenantTestDataBuilder>() // This
                .Build();                                    // This
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the TenantTestDataBuilder code:

```
public class TenantTestDataBuilder : ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IRepository<Tenant, Guid> _tenantRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ITenantManager _tenantManager;

    public TenantTestDataBuilder(
        IRepository<Tenant, Guid> tenantRepository,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ITenantManager tenantManager)
    {
        _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _tenantManager = tenantManager;
    }

    public void Build()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But it fails to get the TenantTestDataBuilder from DI and throws this exception:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.35]       Volo.Abp.AbpInitializationException : An error occurred during the initialize Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributor phase of the module OrderManagement.OrderManagementTestBaseModule, OrderManagement.TestBase, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: An exception was thrown while activating Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityDataSeedContributor -> Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityDataSeeder.. See the inner exception for details.
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.35]       ---- Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while activating Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityDataSeedContributor -> Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityDataSeeder.
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.35]       -------- Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : None of the constructors found with 'Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacConstructorFinder' on type 'Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityDataSeeder' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.35]       Cannot resolve parameter 'Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Volo.Abp.Guids.IGuidGenerator, Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityRoleRepository, Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityUserRepository, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ILookupNormalizer, Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityUserManager, Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityRoleManager, Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.ICurrentTenant, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions])'.
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.35]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleManager.InitializeModules(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationBase.InitializeModules()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationWithExternalServiceProvider.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Testing.AbpIntegratedTest`1..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         /home/mahdi/Desktop/d/Repos/ordermanagement/aspnet-core/test/OrderManagement.TestBase/OrderManagementTestBase.cs(25,0): at OrderManagement.OrderManagementTestBase`1..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         /home/mahdi/Desktop/d/Repos/ordermanagement/aspnet-core/test/OrderManagement.TestBase/TestData/UnitTestData_Tests.cs(14,0): at OrderManagement.TestData.UnitTestData_Tests..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Data.DataSeeder.SeedAsync(DataSeedContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapter.ProceedAsync()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         /home/mahdi/Desktop/d/Repos/ordermanagement/aspnet-core/test/OrderManagement.TestBase/OrderManagementTestBaseModule.cs(59,0): at OrderManagement.OrderManagementTestBaseModule.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SeedTestData>b__0>d.MoveNext()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<Run>b__0(Task t)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Threading.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 action)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         /home/mahdi/Desktop/d/Repos/ordermanagement/aspnet-core/test/OrderManagement.TestBase/OrderManagementTestBaseModule.cs(55,0): at OrderManagement.OrderManagementTestBaseModule.SeedTestData(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         /home/mahdi/Desktop/d/Repos/ordermanagement/aspnet-core/test/OrderManagement.TestBase/OrderManagementTestBaseModule.cs(50,0): at OrderManagement.OrderManagementTestBaseModule.OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributor.Initialize(ApplicationInitializationContext context, IAbpModule module)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleManager.InitializeModules(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]         ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetAllBindings(ConstructorBinder[] availableConstructors, IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__11_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DelegateMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<PropertiesAutowired>b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DelegateMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`3.<EnableInterfaceInterceptors>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DelegateMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.36]            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.37]   Finished:    OrderManagement.TestBase
----- Test Execution Summary -----
```

What could be wrong? I am doing like ABP Framework's [AbpTenantManagementTestBaseModule](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/48c52625f4c4df007f04d5ac6368b07411aa7521/modules/tenant-management/test/Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.TestBase/Volo/Abp/TenantManagement/AbpTenantManagementTestBaseModule.cs).

Here is the template that I used from https://abp.io/get-started

- Project type: Application
- UI Framework: Angular
- Database provider: Entity Framework Core
- Database management system: MySQL
- Mobile: ReactNative
- Separate Identity Server: Checked

Running OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Volo.Abp.Identity.IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository' ...
> ...
> .../ordermanagement/aspnet-core/test/OrderManagement.TestBase/TestData/UnitTestData_Tests.cs(14,0): at OrderManagement.TestData.UnitTestData_Tests..ctor()
> ```

You should not write tests in `OrderManagement.TestBase` project.

Move `OrderManagement.TestBase/TestData/UnitTestData_Tests.cs`
to `OrderManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.Tests/TestData/UnitTestData_Tests.cs`

```cs
// public class UnitTestData_Tests: OrderManagementTestBase<OrderManagementTestBaseModule>
   public class UnitTestData_Tests: OrderManagementEntityFrameworkCoreTestBase
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, moving the test from TestBase project to EntityFramework test project resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your `SeedTestData` method. Because it's responsible for seed your test data. You don't need to add `TenantTestDataBuilder` to seed your tenant-related data. It's also responsible for that too.

```cs
private static void SeedTestData(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
        {
            AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () =>
            {
                using (var scope = context.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    await scope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<IDataSeeder>()
                        .SeedAsync();
                }
            });
        }
```

You only need to seed your data in the `YourTestDataSeedContributor` class's `SeedAsyncMethod`.

```cs
public class YourTestDataSeedContributor : IDataSeedContributor, ITransientDependency 
{
   private readonly ITenantRepository _tenantRepository;
   private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
   private readonly ITenantManager _tenantManager;

   public YourTestDataSeedContributor(ITenantRepository tenantRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ITenantManager tenantManager)
   {
      _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
      _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
       _tenantManager = tenantManager;
   }
   
   public async Task SeedAsync(DataSeedContext context)
   {
      await AddTenantsAsync();
   }

   public async Task AddTenantsAsync()
   {
      var testData = new OrderManagementTestData();
      var tenant = await CreateTenantAsync(testData.DefaultTenantName);
   }

   private async Task<Tenant> CreateTenantAsync(string name)
   {
      var tenant = await _tenantManager.CreateAsync(name);
        
      await _tenantRepository.InsertAsync(tenant);
      await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        
      return tenant;
   }
}
```

After you seed your data in the `SeedAsyncMethod`, you can use it in your tests.

Comment: I was using a test test data contributor exactly like you described, however I was facing this issue, then I referred to the GitHub repo of abp and found that example and changed accordingly which I ended up with the same problem.  Just for testing your suggestion, I re-extracted the created zip containing the initial abp template project to make sure I am working a fresh project. and I only added the "YourTestDataSeedContributor" and again the same issue. It cannot resolve the tenant repository for some reason!